# Check if the string is syntactically true

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I am trying to solve a task with regex. Given a function with string parameter .The string contains `(){}<>[]` braces. I have to check if the string is syntactically true and I should also take a count of braces nesting. 
This is my version (incomplete)`

```
const checkBraces = (str) => {
  const newStr = str.replace(/[^(){}<>[\]]+/gi, '');
  let answer = newStr.match(/\(+\)+|\<+\>+|\{+\}+|\[+\]+/g);
  console.log(answer);
}
```

and this is the minimal count of tests for the function `

```
checkBraces("---(++++)----") == 0
checkBraces("") == 0
checkBraces("before ( middle []) after ") == 0
checkBraces(") (") == 1
checkBraces("} {") == 1
checkBraces("<(   >)") == 1
checkBraces("(  [  <>  ()  ]  <>  )") == 0
checkBraces("   (      [)") == 1
```

If there is en error so the function should return 1 , else 0 .
In my function I first tried to replace all `non-braces` so I have a clear string. Now I can't solve this problem .

Comment: Do you have to use regular expressions?

Comment: This looks like a situation where you'd just want to build a string parser and go character by character.

Comment: no , it's not mandatory to use it , but i think only with regex i can solve it

Comment: `I am trying to solve a task with RegEx` is there a particular reason you want to do that? Are you open to using better alternatives? A regex is *possible* but will be ugly at the very least and quite hard to maintain.

Comment: no i can use another solutions , just i thought regex is the best solution .

Comment: This type of question has been asked in the past. Might want to look at solutions others have done with those questions.

Comment: I couldnt find a question similar to this .

Comment: `but i think only with regex i can solve it` quite the contrary - a regex is probably one of the worst tools to solve this. If you just want to match braces, it's simple enough to do using a stack - go through the string character by character, add opening braces to the stack as you encounter them, then pop them off when you find a matching closing bracket. In fact, you can reduce it to a simple counter and just keep several of them for each brace type.

Comment: There ara cases like this `"(<)>"` . In this case your version is not working

Comment: Sorry, you are right - the counters won't work. But a stack still does. If you encounter a closing brace and the top of the stack does NOT match, then you have an invalid brace positioning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can solve this by iterating through the string and keeping a stack of opening braces. Each time you find a closing brace, pop from the stack. The closing brace should match the thing you popped or they're not balanced. At the end the stack should be empty:

```js
let braces = { // lookup to match closing with opening
    '(':')',
    '{':'}',
    '<':'>',
    '[':']'
}
let closing = new Set([')', '}', '>', ']']) // quick lookup of brackets
let opening = new Set(['(', '{', '<', '['])

function checkBraces(str) {
    /* returns true if balanced, false if unbalanced */
    let stack = []
    for (l of str){
        if (closing.has(l)){                            // found a closing bracket
            if (l !== braces[stack.pop()]) return false // does it match the last opening?
        } else if(opening.has(l)) stack.push(l)         // found an opening push to the stack
    }
    return stack.length === 0 
}
console.log(checkBraces("before ( middle []) after "))
console.log(checkBraces("<(   >)"))
console.log(checkBraces("(  [  <>  ()  ]  <>  )"))
console.log(checkBraces("   (      [)"))
console.log(checkBraces(" )"))
console.log(checkBraces(" <"))
```

Comment: Excelent solution .Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Not using any inbuilt function except `push` and `pop`.

```
function check(s) {
  var arr = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === '{' || s[i] === '[' || s[i] === '(' || s[i] === '<' ) {
        arr.push(s[i]);
    } else if (s[i] === '}' || s[i] === ']' || s[i] === ')' || s[i] === '>' ) {
        if ( arr[arr.length-1] === s[i] ) {
            arr.pop();
        } else {
            return 'not balanced';
        }
    }
  }
  if(arr.length) return 'not balanced';
  return 'balanced';
}

console.log(check('{781234}[3,4,5,6         ]<       >( sdfhniusdf  )'));
console.log(check('asssssssssss {}');
console.log(check(' as<  habsdj');
```